# Are there singular matrices such that if we change any entry it will be non-singular?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Prove or disprove: for each natural $n$ there exists an $n \times n$ matrix
with real entries such that its determinant is zero, but if one changes any single
entry one gets a matrix with non-zero determinant.

I think we may be able to construct such matrices.

Comment: Well, for one thing, you could do this with a $1\times 1$ matrix. But even for $2\times 2$ you can just put the same (non-zero) element in all entries.

Comment: I'd actually venture to say *most* singular matrices are have this property. Most matrices are going to be nonsingular because the conditions for having a zero determinant are so specific, if you choose a matrix at random it's likely to be nonsingular.

Comment: When you say "if one changes any single entry" do you mean that in the sense that the entry could be changed to _anything_ and make the determinant nonzero? Or that for any entry, there would be _some_ number you could change it to that would make the determinant nonzero?

Comment: @alex.jordan the question wants a matrix with determinant zero but all non-zero minors.  In that case, changing any number by $dx$ will change the determinant from zero to $dx$ times the minor.

Answer (score 1):

Choose any matrix with rank $n-1$ that does not have any of the standard unit vectors in its column space.

**Added** in response to the comment by alex.jordan.

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix with $rank(A) = n-1$ such that there are vectors $a, \, \tilde a$ with $Aa = 0, \tilde a^T A  = 0$ that have all entries $ a_i , \tilde a_i \ne 0$. Then any matrix $B$ that differs from $A$ in exactly one entry has full rank, i.e. $\det B \ne 0$.

To prove this, consider such a $B$. After permuting rows and columns and rescaling, we may assume that $B_{1,1} = A_{1,1} + 1$.

First note that the first column of $A$ is a linear combination of columns $2, \dots, n$, since $Aa = 0$ and $a_1 \ne 0$. The column space of $B$ certainly contains the column space of $A$ and thus  $rank(B) \ge n-1$.

If $rank(B) < n$, then $A$ and $B$ must therefore have the same column space. Hence the standard unit vector $e_1$ is in the column space of $A$, that is $Ac = e_1$ for some vector $c$. But then $0 = \tilde a^TAc = \tilde a e_1 = \tilde a_1$, contradicting the assumptions for the left and right null vectors of $A$.

Therefore $rank(B) > n-1$ and $\det B \ne 0$.

Comment: This isn't enough. You could have a $3\times3$ matrix with the first two columns identical and an independent third column. Then the rank is $n-1$, but altering the right column entries does not make the matrix nonsingular.

Comment: Good point, I'll reconsider my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let all the entries of the matrix be algebraically independent except for one entry chosen so that the determinant is zero and the matrix is singular. The algebraic independence guarantees that if you change any entry by a small amount then you make a nonzero change in the determinant and get a nonsingular matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Yes (for $n>1$), in fact almost every (in some quite generic sense) singular matrix has this property.

To see this we observe that the property can be expressed else-way as a stronger property. Any matrix with one-dimensional null-space and where the rows/columns are all linearly dependent (that is can be written as a linear combination with all coefficients being non-zero).

To put it in laymans terms it's that it's very unlikely that the spanning vectors are lineary dependent, and given they are and we single out one that can be described as a linear combination of the other it's very unlikely that the remaining are lineary dependent. This means that given a singular matrix it's almost sure that it has null space of dimension one, and it's very unlikely that the null space would align with one of the axes.

The assumption is a measure $\mu$ on the set of (singular) matrices that is invariant under rotation of the coordinate system, assigns bounded hypersurfaces (and subset thereof) finite measure, assigns surfaces of lesser dimension a null measure (and assigns a the set of singular matrices bounded by a positive radius a positive measure).

So what we have to prove is that the set of matrices that have one of the axes as null-space (the other sets with null space of dimension larger than one forms a surface of dimension less than $n-1$ and are therefore of zero measure).

To prove that the set of matrices that has one of the axes as null-space is to have a $r>0$ and consider the set $B_r$ of matrices such that $||A||<r$, now $\mu(B_r)>0$. Now consider the set of matrices in $B_r$ with null space being one of the axes, now we can by rotation create infinite number of disjoint sets $S_j$ having different (one dimension) null spaces. Now we have $\bigcup S_j\subseteq B_r$ so $\sum\mu S_j = \mu\left(\bigcup S_j\right) < \mu(B_r)$, but as $\mu(S_j)$ are all the same we must conclude that $\mu(S_j) = 0$.

Finally we have to prove that the matrices that have one dimensional null-space, but where the rows/columns are not all linearly dependent have null measure. This is done by showing that they form a surface of dimension less than $n\times n-1$. To show this we create parameterizations of the surfaces. This is done by noting that such a matrix can be determined by specifying all rows except one that is linearly dependent on the other together with the linear combination of the other rows. Normally this means that we have $n\times(n-1)$ coordinates for the rows, and the linear combination gives $n-1$ more coordinates. However if we put the restriction that one of them is not dependent on the others we have a situation where one of the coefficients in the linear combination is zero which leaves us with less than $n-1$ more coordinates. Now this approach will result in one parameterization for each independent row we select and one for each dependent row we select, but there is finite number of combinations.

To see why the condition is sufficient now consider rows $u_j$ and coefficients $c_j\ne 0$ such that $\sum c_ju_j = 0$, and assume that the null-space of the matrix doesn't align with any axis. The property is to say that $\xi e_k$ added to any of the $u_j$ will result in the vectors being independent. Now assume that we add to $u_1$ and assume that we have a linear combination that equals zero, then we would have $\xi e_k + \sum b_ju_j = 0$, which means that $e_k = -\xi^{-1}\sum b_ju_j$ which means that $e_k$ is in the range of the matrix and therefore not in the null space.

Comment: If an $n \times n$ matrix has full rank, then any other matrix that differs from it in one element has rank $n-1$. So at least that requirement must be added to your condition.

Comment: @HansEngler I don't see why, where do I use that assumption? That simply isn't true - if a matrix has full rank you can always change one element in some way to get another matrix of full rank.

Comment: Sorry - my comment was incomplete. The property that the null space of $A$ does not contain any standard unit vectors is not sufficient to guarantee that there are non-singular matrices that differ from $A$ in one entry. A counterexample is a matrix $A$ that has all entries equal to 1 and that has more than two columns. No standard unit vector is in the null space and no  matrix that differs from $A$ in one entry is invertible.

Comment: @HansEngler Yes, but that counter example has a null space of $2$ dimensions. These are ruled out by the assumption that a surfaces of lower dimension having null measure. However I agree should also handle the situation where the rows/columns are dependent in a way that not all rows/columns are lineary dependent on the others.

Comment: I claim that the last situation is covered by the rule that surfaces with dimension lower than $n\times n-1$ are assigned null measure.

Comment: I see that you have edited your answer, and I don't see a problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at $$M=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&\cdots&\cdots&0&(-1)^n\\1&1&0&\cdots&\cdots&0&0\\0&1&1&\cdots&\cdots&0&0\\0&0&1&\ddots&\cdots&0&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\0&0&0&\cdots&\ddots&1&0\\0&0&0&\cdots&\cdots&1&1\end{bmatrix}$$

$M$ is singular because the alternating sum of the first $n-1$ columns gives you the last column: $$(-1)^nc_1+(-1)^{n+1}c_2+\cdots+(-1)^{n+(n-2)}c_{n-1}=c_n$$

What happens if a $0$ is changed to a $1$? Or a $\pm1$ is changed to a $0$?

[Hint: consider this matrix over the field $\mathbb{F}_2$. Over that field it's easier to show that the resulting columns would be linearly independent. This implies no nontrivial integer-linear combination on $M$'s columns can be zero, when $M$ is viewed as a matrix over $\mathbb{Z}$ (since a reduced form of that linear combination would involve at least one odd scalar). And that in turn implies no nontrivial rational-linear combination on $M$'s columns can be zero when $M$ is viewed as a matrix over $\mathbb{Q}$ (since otherwise you could multiply through by a least common denominator). And since all entries are rational, no nontrivial real-linear combination on $M$'s columns can be zero when $M$ is viewed as a matrix over $\mathbb{R}$.]

Answer (score 0):

If you want a constructive proof, the following example works over any field. Consider the $n\times n$ matrix
$$
A=\pmatrix{I_{n-1}&-\mathbf1_{n-1}\\ -\mathbf1_{n-1}^T&n-1},
$$
where $\mathbf1_{n-1}$ is the all-one vector. Since $A$ is a symmetric rank-$(n-1)$ matrix whose null space is spanned by $\mathbf 1_n$, its adjugate is a scalar multiple of the all-one matrix $\mathbf 1_n\mathbf 1_n^T$. As the $(n,n)$-th minor of $A$ is equal to $1$, we see that $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ is precisely $\mathbf 1_n\mathbf 1_n^T$. Therefore, by the rank-one update formula for determinant, we have
\begin{aligned}
\det(A+ae_ie_j^T)
&=\det(A)+ae_j^T\operatorname{adj}(A)e_i\\
&=\det(A)+ae_j^T\mathbf1_n\mathbf1_n^Te_i\\
&=\det(A)+a\\
&=a.\\
\end{aligned}